# index an object with the keyof an interface while the value is a function with the return type of that key

Tags: typescript

Here's what I have as an interface:

```
interface Person{
    name: string
    age: number
    hobbies: string[]
}



const processors : {[functioname: keyof Person}: (value: string)=> Person[fuctionname]} =
{
    name: (value)=>{}//must return string
    age: (value)=>{}//must return a number
}
```

I want the processors to be funcitons indexed by the key and return a value of the same type

so if the key is name, the return type should be string like in the interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Type[key]` construction.

Here is an example, pay attention to the `type Proc<T>`

```js
interface Person{
    name: string
    age: number
    hobbies: string[]
}


type Proc<T> = {
    [key in keyof T]: ()=> T[key]
}

const processors : Proc<Person> =
{
    name: ()=>'',//must return string
    age: ()=>5,//must return a number
    hobbies: ()=> []
}
```